# copy command in macOS returning directory not found

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

so I am using Visual Studio and I am trying to run a python project this is the command from my tasks.json that I am trying to run:

```
cp -r ${workspaceRoot}/lambda/py/ ${workspaceRoot}/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/
```

But I am getting:

```
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/interceptors/__init__.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/interceptors/LocalizationInterceptor.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/hello_world.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/locales: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/lambda/py//locales: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/locales: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/locales/strings.en.json: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/locales/strings.es.json: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/requirements.txt: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/lambda/py//intents: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents/HelloWorldIntentHandler.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents/LaunchRequestHandler.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents/__init__.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents/CancelOrStopIntentHandler.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents/HelpIntentHandler.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents/SessionEndedRequestHandler.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/intents/IntentReflectorHandler.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/errors: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/lambda/py//errors: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/errors: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/errors/__init__.py: No such file or directory
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/errors/CatchAllExceptionHandler.py: No such file or directory
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'cp -r /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/lambda/py/ /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

I executed cd /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/

and it says the directory is not there but if I use the finder I can get into that folder.

Does anyone knows why is this happening? How can I fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

May be it is a problem with extended file attributes, from your log:

```
cp: /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/lambda/py//errors: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/raulgarcia/Desktop/skills/alexa-python-lambda-helloworld/.venv/skill_env/lib/python3.9.2/site-packages/errors: No such file or directory
```

See [What Are Mac File Extended Attributes And How To Remove And Use Them](https://softwaretested.com/mac/what-are-mac-file-extended-attributes-and-how-to-remove-and-use-them/)